# Stuck on detecting file system Ubuntu 16.04 install

Tags: system-installation

I added the ISO on grub2 in my Kali Linux, then I restarted and loaded the Ubuntu from the ISO on grub2. I started the Ubuntu install and I followed the usual installation guide with partitioning making and all and I get stuck on detecting file system. Here are some screen shots:

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: I can't help choose either one of the options since i added the ubuntu iso manually into the Grub2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally excounter this problem if the partition containing the ISO file is in the same drive as the target partition. This is because the installer likes to unmount all mounted partitions in the target drive before proceeding with installation.

My system has two (2) drives. I was able to circumvent this problem by moving the ISO file to the other drive.

Unfortunately for single-drive systems, I have never been able to use the loop mount feature of grub2 to install directly from ISO file. The LiveCD will boot just fine, but won't install on the same drive.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the problem ,So if i just create another partition and move the ISO to the new partition it solves the problem and installs just fine